# Why numpy.astype didn't work when I want to convert a float32 numpy into a uint8 numpy and then convert it to ctypes.Pointer(c_ubyte)?

Tags: numpy, ctypes

I want to exploit python.ctypes to transmit a image numpy into a C++ function. But the input of C++ function is not exactly the same as that image numpy. The specific data conversion: numpy.float32 -- numpy.uint8 --ctypes.Pointer(ctypes.c_ubyte). 
The code:

```
color_in = np.asarray(color,dtype=np.uint8).ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint8))
```

Then I print color_in.contents and it shows"c_ubyte(144)" while color[0,0,0]= 92.0. The value changed. It seemed  that numpy.float32 didn't convert into numpy.uint8 successfully.I was confused.

Then I split the code into two lines as belows.

```
color_wb = np.asarray(color,dtype=np.uint8)
color_in = color_wb.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte))
```

The result of 'print(color_in.contents)' is 'c_ubyte(92)'.

Afterwards, I tried some test.

```
a = np.asarray(color[0:2,0:2,:],dtype=np.uint8).ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint8))
print(a.contents)
b = np.asarray(color[0,:,:],dtype=np.uint8).ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint8))
print(b.contents)
b = np.asarray(color[:,0,:],dtype=np.uint8).ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint8))
print(b.contents)
c = np.asarray(color[:,:,0],dtype=np.uint8).ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint8))
print(c.contents)
d = np.asarray(color[:,:,:],dtype=np.uint8).ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint8))
print(d.contents)
```

The results are:

```
>>>c_ubyte(92)
c_ubyte(92)
c_ubyte(92)
c_ubyte(192)
c_ubyte(144)
```

If I take all of  fisrt two dimensions of this matrix, the np.asarray(matrix,dtype =xx) won't work. I'm so confused.

================================
python version:python2.7

Comment: You should also include (part of) your *color* array. [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But on the 1st glance, take a look at *float**32*** and *uint**8***. One takes 32 bits, and the other takes 8. Most of the *32bit* values can't possibly fit in 8 bits, so they will be truncated.

Comment: So sorry about this. This color array is obtained from 
```
cv2.imread("./pic/bw.bmp").astype(np.float32)
```  
The value in this array is limited in 0-255.

Comment: You do realize that people can't reproduce your scenario: `color = cv2.imread("./pic/bw.bmp").astype(np.float32)`. That's why I was saying to initialize *color* to some values from the image, and place it here, to have something to work with.